# Batch remove all characters after a specific character in filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am dealing about 6000+ picture files to be renamed.

Conditions:

1. filename is in this format: Specific name A-0000.jpg
2. i need to retain the Specific name and just remove everything after a specific character: output must be: Specific name.jpg --- where A can be any variables that I can define
3. is it also possible that the letter "A" or defined variable is the very last variable? because when the filename is: "One Android A-12123.jpg" the output becomes "One.jpg"

specific name is unique for every file
example file names:

1. mountain A-3124.jpg
2. big tree B-442655.jpg
3. house in sea S-99028.jpg

File directories are in this format:

```
|- pics
|-- folder1
|----- file1
|----- file2
|----- ......
|-- folder2
|----- file1
|----- file2
|----- ......
|-- more folders...
```

i just got started with this:

```
import os
specialchar = 'A'

for file in os.listdir("pics"):
   file = text.split(specialchar, 1)[0]
   os.rename(file,f"/pics/{file}")
```

**update:**
I am now able to change the filename of the specific files outside the other folders but I cannot change those files inside the subfolders. Also, there is a space between the extension

```
import os
specialchar = "S"
path = "E:/pics/"
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in enumerate(files):
   newname = file.split(specialchar, 1)[0] + ".jpg"
   os.rename(os.path.join(path,file),os.path.join(path,newname))
```

I do not know why it won't work.

Comment: In your code snippet, what is `text`?

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `python-requests` tag

Comment: @quamrana ohhhhh so I think it should be, file.split ? but still wont work

Comment: @Daweo sorry I did not know that python requests is different. I though it is "request" for requesting an answer. Sorry

Comment: @anatolyg Specific name is unique to every file. I just placed specific name as an example. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
import os
import sys

specialchar = 'A'

# get current working directory (where your script is saved) 
curr_dir = sys.path[0]
# create path to pics directory
pics_dir = os.path.join(curr_dir, "pics")

# loop through pics directory
for f in os.listdir(pics_dir):
    # construct new filename
    new_name = f.split(specialchar, 1)[0]
    # rename file in current working directory - use strip() to remove whitespace
    os.rename(f"{pics_dir}/{f}", f"{pics_dir}/{new_name.strip()}.jpg")
```

--EDIT--

You need to find all subdirectories in the 'pics' directory then iterate through those. Your example filenames contain a "-" next to the character you want to split so adding "A-" will allow the correct split to be made:-

```
import os
import sys
specialchar = 'A-'

# get current working directory (where your script is saved) 
curr_dir = sys.path[0]
# create path to pics directory
pics_dir = os.path.join(curr_dir, "pics")
# get all folders in pics dir
all_folders = [fdr for fdr in os.listdir(pics_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(pics_dir, fdr))]

# loop through each folder
for fdr in all_folders:
    # create new path
    work_dir = os.path.join(pics_dir, fdr)
    # loop through specific subfolder
    for f in os.listdir(work_dir):
        # check if object is not a directory
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(work_dir, f)):
            # construct new filename
            new_name = f.split(specialchar, 1)[0]
            # rename file - use strip() to remove whitespace
            os.rename(f"{work_dir}/{f}", f"{work_dir}/{new_name.strip()}.jpg")
```

Comment: this is a good one! but it has the same error as mine. the folder gets the extension .jpg and the files inside the folder does not get the rename

Comment: I also added another condition that will help to solve some bugs: is it also possible that the letter "A" or defined variable is the very last variable? because when the filename is: "One Android A-12123.jpg" the output becomes "One.jpg"

Comment: it works great!!!! can you help me with additional matter? 2 matters actually
1. how can I loop the specialchar from A- to Z- so it will reduce my workload in going through every folders to see the letters embedded.
2. i also just saw that 2 pics has the same names! :( can I add "1" for the first file and "2" to the other file?

thank you so much for solving this 1 week long problem I am having

Comment: I hope I can still bother you with my request